# Could you help me to insert a background color for a specific row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is my data frame:
[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xzn.png)

I want at the column endingBalanceLC  the total which corespond to the account 121(I have to make synt of 3 because I need just 3 digits) from accountNumber column to be colored in yellow. The problem is that I don't know exactly where this account and the aferent total are in my dataframe, because the position can always change,depends the excel.

This is my current code:

```
df=pd.read_excel("GLAB.xlsx")
left=df['accountNumber'].str[:3]
account=(left=='121')
def color(val):
    if val==account:
        color = 'yellow'
    elif val!=account:
        color = 'white'
   
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(color, subset=['endingBalanceLC'])
```

I didn't receive errors but I can colored the cell with this condition

Comment: I didn't understand your question: are you asking a) how to format column "endingBalanceLC" based on value of "accountNumber" or b) how to check the value of "accountNumber" if the column position changes on different Excel files?

Comment: How I can format column endingBalanceLC based on value of 'accountNumber"?

Comment: The problem is that account 121 is not necessarily the last or in the middle of the column, it always depends on the excel. But all I need to do is to color endingBalanceLC which corespond 121 account

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If not please add more information how it could be more helpful.

Comment: I saw that the column isaccount apears true in front  of accountNumber 121, but it doesn't color my endingBalance in yellow.

Comment: Really? The output I have can be seen here: https://imgur.com/a/kEpLkKR

Comment: Please provide more information about the issue you are experiencing: How are trying to use the styled DataFrame? Have you modified the code from my answer? What editor are you using? What is your Pandas version (`pd.__version__`)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eZAgwEW -I tried to use the same code like you wrote me. My editor is sublime text and the pandas version is 1.3.3

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this solves your problem. Welcome on SO btw, please read about improving your questions as this last information would have save me some work if I had known it before. Please don't forget to formally accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Styling DataFrame HTML representation

I would divide your task into two steps: first make a helper column for marking rows to highlight, second format your dataframe based on the helper column and the column to highlight.

```
df = pd.read_excel("GLAB.xlsx")

# helper column to show wheather 'accountNumber' fulfills the specified condition
df['isAccount'] = df['accountNumber'].apply(lambda v: v.startswith('121'))

def highlight(x):
    # temporary empty dataframe with same columns and index
    _df = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    # fill columns filtered by isAccount value
    _df.loc[x['isAccount'], :] = ['', 'background-color: yellow']
    _df.loc[~x['isAccount'], :] = ['', 'background-color: white']
    return _df

df.style.apply(highlight, subset=['isAccount', 'endingBalanceLC'], axis=None)
```

This will create a styled HTML representation of your DataFrame.

[image: styled df repr]

### Styling Excel output file

If however you need to save the DataFrame to xlsx format and format the output file, you need something different. Instead of a styler object, which works in editors that handle HTML tables, you need to format the Excel file itself, and use python code only as an interface. One module than is integrated with pandas and allows to format xlsx files is [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html). So you need something like the code below, though you'll probably need to modify the formula variable to fit your use case.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'accountNumber': ['1012', '1012000', '105', '121'],
    'endingBalanceLC': [0.00, -102297590.00, 0.00, 6000.00],
    'financialPeriod': [12,12,12,12],
    'debitCreditIndicator': ['D', 'C', 'D','D']
})
df['isAccount'] = df['accountNumber'].apply(lambda v: v.startswith('121'))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})
worksheet.conditional_format('C1:C250', 
{'type':'formula', 
'criteria': '=F1=TRUE',  
'format': yellow
})
writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Why isn't working if my first line of code is df=pd.read_excel('GLAB.XLSX) ?

Comment: I succided,thanks

Comment: I have one more question for you. Can I add a coment in  the cell which i made in yellow? For example this is a' balance amount"?

Comment: Sure you can, but adding a cell comment is completely different topic than conditional formatting. You can read more in xlsxwriter documentation - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_comments.html . If you fail to implement just post another SO question.